# Passing nsIDOMHTMLSelectElement as function parameter causes exception

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-select

The following script gets such an error messsage:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 
[nsIDOMHTMLSelectElement.add]" nsresult: 
"0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: 
"JS frame :: file:///D:/programming/temp/js_bug/page.html 
:: addOption :: line 13" data: no]
```

A piece of HTML with script:

```
<form name = "form">
    <select name = "select">
    </select>            
</form>
<script>
    //This way of adding an option fails  
    function addOption(selectElement, optionText)
    {                        
        var option = document.createElement("option")
        option.text = optionText
        selectElement.add(optionText, null);
    }
    element = document.getElementsByName("select")[0]
    addOption(element, "2")
    /* This way of adding an option works
    option = document.createElement("option")
    option.text = "1"
    element.add(option, null)*/
</script>
```

The commented code works correctly. I can see only difference between code that works and code that fails - passing DOM object as function parameter.
I am working on Firefox 3.6.17

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass `option` (not `optionText`) to the `add()` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help and sorry for stupid question :) Work at night sometimes leads to really foolish errors...